# Why there's some "noise" around the edge of my loading gif on my website?

Tags: gif, animated-gif

Why there's some "noise" around the edge of my loading gif on my website?
It should be all grey, but as you can see in the below screenshot, the edge is all screwed up, it looks bad!

[image]

==========================================================================
Edit: attach gif and png snapshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a .png saved snapshot and the original .gif to better observe the difference? Now it's hard to tell if you are referring to some .jpg artifacts or to the aliased edges.

Comment: Transparency in GIF is binary, so any partially-transparent pixels necessarily bake in the background colour that you chose when you encoded it.

Comment: @harold, you mean for different background color, I need to prepare different gif?

Comment: For this picture, yes. If you had simple jagged edges, you wouldn't have to.

Comment: Have you consider using an animated SVG instead? There are some [good reasons](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-vs-gif/).

Comment: @Bob__ wowoo.. it looks exactly the solution to the problem I'm current facing, thanks! I'll check it out.